# Ember.js - Routing

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-router

I have such issue: need to create a date picker, with url “/year/xxxx/month/yy/day/zz,
where  xxxx, yy and zz would be the year, month and day of the selected date.

This code is for generating url of index page:

```
  App.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('years', {path: '/'},function(){
   this.resource("year", { path: "/year/:year_id" }, function() {
    this.resource("month",{path:"/month/:month_id"},function(){
      this.resource("day",{path:"/day/:day_id"});
    });
  });
  });
});

App.YearsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function(param)
  {
    var rec =App.Model.createRecord({
      year:2013,
      month:8,
      day:28,
      id:1
    });
    this.transitionTo('year',rec);
  }
});

App.YearRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect:function(param){ 
    this.transitionTo('month',param);  
  },
  serialize:function(param){
   return {year_id: param.get('year')}; 
  }
});

App.MonthRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect:function(param)
  {
    this.transitionTo('day',param);  
  },
  serialize:function(param){
    return {month_id:param.get('month')};
  }  
});

App.DayRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  serialize:function(param){
    return {day_id:param.get('day')};
  } 
});
```

How to create a buttons that change year/month/day and where contain them and handle-logic ?

Answer (score 0):

We ended up using this solution to pick dates in our ember.js app: http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker

It required some styling updates but other than that was pretty easy to implement.